# Azure AD application only allowing admins

Tags: azure-active-directory

[image]

As you can see from the image, it's not letting regular users login to the application. How do I bring down this access to members? This is an azure active directory application. I can login just fine with an admin user but my regular accounts gets blocked. Note, I created the application with the regular account. I don't suppose this has something to do with it?

I've granted the app all delegated permissions. No application permissions though. I'm thinking there's something in the manifest I need to alter but I'm not sure and I've never messed with this before. So any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to perform admin consent for the application.  There are two ways to do this in Azure AD:

1. In the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com), you can go into the ***App Registrations*** blade, then click on the App, click on ***Permissions***, and hit `Grant Permissions`.
2. Construct a request to Azure AD with the extra parameter `&prompt=admin_consent`.

For example:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<AppID>&resource=<Resource App ID URI>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<Redirect URI>&prompt=admin_consent`

Comment: It was the  Grant Permissions I apparently didn't do. I thought I hit that but I think I did that on my regular user account and not the admin account. Thanks